# ¿Cómo resolver un error al compilar un Makefile en VScode?

Tags: vscode, makefile

Esté es el mensaje que me arroja al compilar el `Makefile` en terminal:

```
make : El término 'make' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de
script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, 
si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ make edo
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (make:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a utilizar gitbash - zsh - bash (otra terminal) ya que efectivamente, para usar make tienes que instalar make y agregarlo al path de powershell que en tu caso es la terminal que estás utilizando y tengo entendido que no es posible realmente.
si tienes WIndows Subsystem For Linux puedes correrlo sin problemas y si tienes Docker Desktop puedes crear un contenedor y correrlo allí dentro.